# Duplicated information in data dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I found that in the file in the data dump, the information are duplicated.
In fact, the post with the id 5022383 and the title "Monkey patching CKEditor to embed YouTube videos"  is in the file posts.xml of the months april 2011, june 2011, september 2011 and december 2011 of the stackoverflow's data.

Why is that the case?
How is the data dump built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why wouldn't that be the case? Unless the content is deleted, it will appear in the data dump, as the data dump is, as the name implies, a full dump of the data. Put another way, the data dump is distributed as a snapshot, not a delta.

You should expect it to reflect the state of the site at the point in time when the data dump was released.

Comment: Imagine if it were the delta. You'd have to get each month from the beginning and process them to get them up to date. Wait... is that what the OP was trying?

Comment: Thank's. It's what I thought.

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought at the beginning that it was the delta. My bad.

Comment: So, on which criterion are the posts deleted?

Comment: @user183870 They won't appear in the data dump if they've been deleted on the site, and they can be deleted on the site for various moderation-related reasons.